# Failed to get bootstrap index from server

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to do code analysis for sonarqube. However, I got the error when running

> mvm sonar:sonar

This is the error message:

```
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-06T08:51:52+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project example-java-maven: Unable to execute SonarQube: 
Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url 
[http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [504] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

But when I access http://localhost:9000 via the browser, I can see the sonarqube homepage.

So why could this be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Anything relevant in your server logs? (`$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs`)

Comment: access or sonar?

It seems normal to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url \[http://hostname:9095/sonar/batch/index\] is not valid: \[403\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107898/sonarqube-fail-to-get-bootstrap-index-from-server-status-returned-by-url-http)

Answer (score 8):

Try to use sonar-maven-plugin version 3.2 on your pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
  </plugin>
```

This works for me

Comment: The version 3.7.0.1746 version given in the sonar site documentation throwed the same error for me, 3.2 works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i had included proxy settings in the past in the Maven's `conf/settings.xml` file. Removing or commenting out those corporate proxy settings solved the issue.