# SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://hostname:9095/sonar/batch/index] is not valid: [403]

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to execute following maven command from jenkins job,
 `mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://hostname:9095/sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=mavensample -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin -X`

But it fails with following error,

```
[DEBUG] 18:20:49.119 Download: http://hostname:9095/batch/index
[ERROR] 18:20:49.176 SonarQube server [http://hostname:9095] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.920 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-14T18:20:49+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/171M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project my-stc: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://hostname:9095/batch/index] is not valid: [403] -> [Help 1]
```

When I am trying to access http://hostname:9095 in browser it works.

I have also set the base url in sonarqube settings to http://hostname:9095 and tried but its fails with same error.

Sonaqube is installed on same machine as maven and jenkins.

I thought it may be due to proxy(may be I am wrong), So I have set proxy settings in sonar.properties file and tried but no luck.

FYI, It is using following version of sonar-maven plugin,

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) @ my-stc ---
```

Anyone faced same issue earlier ?

Comment: Since Jenkins and SonarQube are on the same machine, perhaps you could try `http://localhost:9095`

Comment: no luck. same error, `[DEBUG] 09:37:25.105 Download: http://localhost:9095/batch/index
[ERROR] 09:37:25.264 SonarQube server [http://localhost:9095] can not be reached`

Comment: Replace 127.0.0.1 or localhost to the network IP of the machine (if running in same machine only)

Answer (score 15):

The issue was with sonar-maven plugin version 3.3
I tried with version 3.2 and it worked. I passed following to maven command line arguments `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar`

Answer (score 11):

I've recently had a very similar problem
For me the resolution is to do with the proxy settings, if you don't have a proxy then skip this answer.

My command

`mvn clean sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.56.101:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin`

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) @ baselineV001-parent ---
[INFO] User cache: /home/developer/.sonar/cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://192.168.56.101:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for baselineV001-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:

... skipping some info lines for brevity (its a big project)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project baselineV001-parent: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://192.168.56.101:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [503] -> [Help 1]
```

The key part of the log being **http://192.168.56.101:9000/batch/index is not valid**. I can curl this url and it works.

After a little thinking about what is different from curl, I have a proxy set in maven settings `~/.m2/settings.xml` but I dont have one set for curl.

To check if proxy is the issue I removed the proxy entry in my settings.xml and then I saw it working and communicating with my sonarqube server

So if you have a proxy, you probably want to specify your sonarqube server as a host in the field `nonProxyHosts` in  `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>intranet-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username/>
      <password/>
      <host>proxy.intra.redacted.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|192.168.56.101</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Also a small point about advising people to use v3.2. It might be a fix, but it shouldn't be the long term answer as v3.2 is currently 3 years old (4 years old come September 2020). I've seen in other threads the sonarsource support team says give us more information about this problem, but on a newer version of sonar-maven-plugin.

Edit 1:
Forgot to say that I could not find a change in the v3.3.0.603 of sonar-maven-plugin at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven, but it seems that versions 3.3.0.603 to current (3.7.0.1746) and probably future versions pay attention to the maven settings for proxies.
You could argue it was a bug in previous versions that they didn't honor maven's proxy settings.
Edit 2: typo

Comment: you literally saved me from googling an entire day on this issue.

Comment: I have proxy in my `settings.xml`, and adding `<nonProxyHosts>` with value `localhost|my own ip` worked!. Like this:
`<nonProxyHosts>localhost|192.x.x.x</nonProxyHosts>`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use sonar-maven-plugin version 3.2 in your pom.xml

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
  <sonar.host.url>http://xxxxx:9000</sonar.host.url>
  <sonar.login>be2fe3y27f07db354983dfxysdsa5256</sonar.login>
  <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
  <sonar.scm.provider>git</sonar.scm.provider>
</properties>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

We had a same issue. In our case both Jenkins and SonarQube were running on the same machine behind a reverse proxy. It resolved our issue after updating sonar host URL to http://localhost:9000.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to solve sonar version issue.

org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-compiler-plugin
3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue exists in org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.sonar-maven-plugin 3.5.0 plugin as well.

Upgrade your POM dependency to use a new Version or some earlier version like 3.2 are also stable.

```
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's giving you the error because the program can't hit the endpoint you specified.

You shouldn't be specifying the port if the URL already has a DNS mapping. 
For example, if http://sonar.yourcompany.com  is already mapped to 123.23.22.10:9000

So your -Dsonar.host.url flag should be: 
-Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.yourcompany.com

You don't need the /sonar at the end of http://sonar.yourcompany.com

Also, sonar runs on port 9000, not 9095.

Answer (score 0):

01 - First thing first, you should go the maven central url :
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/

02 - Then find the sonar-maven-plugin tag lower than 3 years old. For example we are at year 2022, you should then take one which is between [ 2022-2019 ]

[image: sonar-maven-plugins list]

03 - Finally add the entire plugin tag in your mvn verify command

```
mvn -B verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar
```

04 - Rerun your command and hooraah

Comment: This did not work (3.9.x)