# SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [403]

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, maven-3

I have setup the sonarQube Version 6.7.5. Server is up and running. I can access this server from web browser in eclipse also.

From eclipse(version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)), Sonar Maven Plugin launched `mvn sonar:sonar`

Getting following exception :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project <project-name>: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [403] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project <project-name>: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

When I access link `http://localhost:9000/batch/index` from eclipse browser then web browser shows following details: 
`sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-6.7.5.jar|4d51abc8c7a7796c4c6d163561d3aaf8`; means this URL is accessible from eclipse.

As mentioned in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107898/sonarqube-fail-to-get-bootstrap-index-from-server-status-returned-by-url-http/45145576#45145576) I cannot use the sonar maven plugin version 3.2 as i'm having flat modular project structure and it does not work with 3.2

Following Sonar Maven Plugin version does not work for me: 3.5.0.1254, 3.4.1.1168, 3.4.0.905, 3.3.0.603. All versions giving same error as mentioned above.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: A 403 error means that SonarQube forbids the request. As far as I can tell, this means that your server asks for credentials, so you should probably make sure that you provide valid credentials in your analysis parameters.

Comment: I tried with both option: 1. setting sonar.login and sonar.password details in pom file. 2. setting sonar.login with generated token. But getting same error.

Comment: Also tried with -Dsonar.login and -Dsonar.password VM arguments while running mvn sonar:sonar; but it gives same error.

Comment: The user i tried with is admin user having access to groups: sonar-administrators
and sonar-users

Comment: I see similar problem some time ago. Read: [Issue regarding sonarqube jenkins integration](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/issue-regarding-sonarqube-jenkins-integration/551?u=agabrys). Maybe you will find something useful.